# Linq/nHibernate alternatives/equivalents?

Tags: linq

I heard about a very nice Linq/NHibernate alternative O-R bridge, but darnit can't remember its name. I remember their site featured very instructive screencap video tuts by the developers and the tool can be used as a replacement for Linq.

Help! Any pointers?

Comment: Strictly speaking LINQ is not an OR bridge :). LINQ2SQL and LINQ2Entities might be.

Comment: I dug up an old book, Subsonic is what I was looking for.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600622/most-complete-orm-with-linq-support

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this, only evaluated it: [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/). Out of all the ORM products I tried, this was the only one that installed flawlessly and handled our SQL 2008 DB without complaining. Beautiful designer, really -- MS could learn from them.

The devs are friendly, respond VERY fast, and make nightly builds available. If I understand their licensing, its ridiculously cheap. Overall, they really make you want to buy their products.

(And no, I'm not associated with them, just impressed.)

Answer (score 0):

i think you're thinking of [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com)